# Jobs profile settings not maintained from initial setup

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When I set up my Jobs profile, I indicated that I was "Not looking" but when I went back just now and took a look at my CV it lists me as "Open, but not actively looking".

Comment: This is the second report we've received about this. We're looking at it this morning. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your report. This has now been fixed.

Back in the day, whenever you submitted your CV for review using the form below,
you were also opting in to our candidate database and we automatically changed your job search settings from "not looking" to "passively looking for a job".

[image]

The signup/opt in workflow has changed a lot since, and this automatic change of job search state no longer makes sense. I deleted the code and we will not change the job search state settings on your behalf anymore.

Feel free to update [your settings](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/edit/) back to Not Looking <3